# JSON Settings editor in JupyterLab not working?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I recently updated python to the latest version 3.10.5 on my Windows 10 desktop using [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win). Everything went fine, except when I launched `jupyter lab` and found out I can't access the JSON settings editor anymore. I was following the same procedure as always:

- Launching jupyterlab from the terminal using the command `jupyter lab`
- Going to the settings menu and choosing Advanced Settings Editor
- The settings editor GUI is opened as always and I can change settings through the UI, but I prefer using the JSON settings file.
- On the top right of the settings editor there is a button to open the JSON Settings Editor. I click it and nothing happens. This button doesn't do anything. it used to open a text editor with all the JSON settings files. Now it simply does nothing.

I tried reinstalling jupyter lab completly, including removing every custom extension and reseting all setting to the default, and it didn't help. The `JSON Settings Editor` button still doesn't do anything.

Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest JupyterLab release v3.4.4. I have [reproduced it on 3.4.4](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12891) and opened a pull request to fix it: [jupyterlab#12892](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/12892). The fix should be included in the next patch release. In the meantime you can downgrade to 3.4.3 which is not affected.

Thank you for highlighting it (next time if it looks like a bug feel welcome to report directly at https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues).

Edit: JupyterLab 3.4.5 is now [released](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/releases/tag/v3.4.5). Please upgrade using your package manager to get the fix.

Comment: Amazing. I had spent a while trying to fix this but went down the wrong route due to a harmless `pydevd_plugins.extensions.types.pydevd_plugin_pandas_types` warning —name-dropping it here in case someone is in that same rabbit hole.

Comment: @MatteoFerla How did you fix the `pydevd_plugins.extensions.types.pydevd_plugin_pandas_types` warning?

Comment: Sorry @chuliang-xiao on my system it went away with the subsubversion bump up, so I do not know. But it was not the root of my issues it was a red herring.

Comment: I am using the Jupyterlab on @aws sagemaker. But on the `JSON Setting Editor`, it just shows **Select a plugin from the list to view and edit its preferences.** How to solve this?

Comment: @curiouscheese what is the problem? It always shows this message, you just click on the plugin in the sidebar. If you believe there is a bug please open a bug report.

Comment: @krassowski okay I managed to solve it. Thanks!